# How to use Cloudformation to create an Appflow flow using Microsoft Sharepoint Connector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sharepoint, aws-cloudformation, amazon-appflow

I am trying to deploy a flow that will retrieve files from a sharepoint and move them to AWS S3.

I managed to do it using AWS website but need to industrialize and automate the process using cloudformation. The "Microsoft Sharepoint Online" connector is not an official one, hence I need to use the **CustomConnector** (See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-appflow-flow-customconnectorsourceproperties.html)

On the Sharepoint connector info on AWS we can see that the online *Runtime Settings* to set is called **subEntities** and is described as follows: *JSON Array of folderIds, driveIds that need to be synced (Required, type String)*

I tried several solutions but **I do not know how I am supposed to format this argument** and where to find the driveId/folderId.

I found several values that seems plausibles and tried all the combinations.

At first I had the following error in Cloudformation:

> Error while communicating to connector:
> The request failed because the service Microsoft SharePoint Online returned the following error:
> Details: **invalid Json array of driveId/folder Id**, ErrorCode: InvalidArgument.
> (Service: Appflow, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx)

But now I am using the following template:

```yaml
SourceFlowConfig:
  ApiVersion: v1.0
  ConnectorProfileName: 'myPreviouslyCreatedConnector'
  ConnectorType: CustomConnector
  SourceConnectorProperties:
    CustomConnector:
       CustomProperties:
         subEntities: '["[What I think is driveId]/[What I think is folderId]"]'

       EntityName: Microsoft SharePoint Online
```

But I am getting:

> Error while communicating to connector:
> The request failed because the service Microsoft SharePoint Online returned the following error:
> Details: **Invalid drive Id/folder Id**, ErrorCode: InvalidArgument.
> (Service: Appflow, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx)

I guess I am on a good path as the array seems to be correctly parsed, but cannot find where to go from here.

I found the IDs using the graph api endpoint: `GET /drive/items/[ITEM ID]` that retrieved both driveId and id.

Has someone tried to use cloudformation to create these kind of connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is :

```yaml
CustomProperties:
  subEntities: '["drives/[driveId]/items/[folderId]"]'
```

You can see it using the console network inspector of the web browser while creating the flow using AWS Web Console.

To get those IDs:

1. Call `GET https://[ORGANIZATION].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITENAME]/_api/v2.0/drive/list/items/` and search for you object. In the `eTag` you will have something like `"\"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx,[NUMBER]\""`. You have to use the **xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx** in the next step
2. Call `GET https://[ORGANIZATION].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITENAME]/_api/v2.0/drive/items/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx`
3. Use `driveId` (from *ParentReference*) and the value of the `id` field as your **folderId** (NOT THE xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx FROM STEP 1)

Hoping it will save time to someone.